# Cordova content provider plugin is not working?

Tags: android, cordova, mobile-application, hybrid

#### Cordova Content Provider is not working

I am using this plugin and its not works. while executing this code my application displaying **"XXXX, Stopped unfortunately"** and exit. Any suggestions to fix this issue.

https://github.com/phearme/cordova-ContentProviderPlugin

```
window.plugins.contentproviderplugin.query({
        contentUri: "content://sms/inbox",
        projection: ["address", "date", "body"],
        selection: null,
        selectionArgs: null,
        sortOrder: "date DESC"
    }, function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("error query");
    });
```

Comment: I think it's not problem with code.. When you remove that plugin it works fine ?

Comment: @proofzy : My application is working without this code, This code will trigger when i click the button and that time only am getting that error message after that application closed. 

**Cordova Version : 8**
**Mobile : Motog3**

Comment: Try to update platform cordova